# C segmentation fault using shared library

Tags: c, linux

have to write a program  displaying list of all logged users (their id and groups if -i or -g is used) using shared library. The functions in shared library are working correctly, but it seems like function pointer causes segmentation fault. Since it's a school assigment I have to use C and functions have to return nothing, and take only user name. I'm quite new to programming in linux (obviously).

main code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

struct utmp *p;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


int opt, iflag = 0; 
int gflag = 0;
void *handle;



while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ig")) != -1)
{
    switch(opt)
    {
        case 'i':
            iflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'g':
            gflag = 1;
            break;
        default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Błąd \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}   

handle = dlopen("./zad2lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);

if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open library: %s\n", dlerror());
    iflag = 0;
    gflag = 0; 
}
while ((p = getutent()) != NULL)    {
    if (p->ut_type == USER_PROCESS)
    {
        if (iflag == 1) {
            dlerror();
             void (*func)(char*) = (void(*)())dlsym(handle, "userID");
            func(p->ut_user);

        } 
            printf("%s ", p->ut_user);

        if (gflag == 1) {
            dlerror();  
            void (*func)(char*) = (void(*)())dlsym(handle, "userGroups"); 
            func(p->ut_user);
            }
        }           
        printf("\n");   
    }
    dlclose(handle);
}
return 0;
}
```

.so file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void userID(char *name) {
    struct passwd *pw = getpwnam(name);
    printf("%d ", pw->pw_uid);
}

void userGroups(char *name) {

    struct passwd *pw = getpwnam(name);
    int i;
    int gidsize = 100;
    struct group* g;
    gid_t *grouplist = malloc(gidsize*sizeof(gid_t));
    getgrouplist(name, pw->pw_gid, grouplist, &gidsize);
    printf("[");
    for (i = 0; i < gidsize; i++)   {
        g = getgrgid(grouplist[i]);
        printf(" %s", g->gr_name); 
    }
    printf(" ]");
    free(grouplist);
}
```

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I never heard of such a thing... In fact, C function names are case sensitive.

Comment: your code doesnt compile at all, it just spits load of error and warnings. Do you have code which doesnt have any compilation error?

Comment: amongst other problems, the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` for the function: `printf()`

Comment: the posted code has mis-matched braces.  This is one of many reasons that it does not compile.    When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. and when outputting an error message that was from a call to a OS function, use: `perror()` so the reason the OS thinks the function failed is also output.

Comment: this line: `fprintf(stderr, "Błąd \n");` says nothing about what the problem is.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s [-l] [-g]\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts.  3)  separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: when the function: `dlopen()` fails, do not continue executing the code,  I.E. exit the program in the error handling.  do not proceed to execute:: `while ((p = getutent()) != NULL)`